# Given a network N and an edge (x, y) ∈ E, what is the best algorithm to determine if the edge crosses every mincut of N

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, network-flow

The brute force way to do it would be to calculate all mincuts in N then check if the edge is in the mincut. However, this would be extremely inefficent.

I was thinking of using a maxflow algorithm to get a more efficient solution. I've been told that there is a O(V+E+timeofmaxflowalgo)solution.
Any thoughts and ideas how this could be implemented.

Comment: s-t min cut or global min cut?

Comment: s-t min cut, not global

Comment: Compute a max flow. A cut is a min cut if and only if it is crossed only by arcs with zero residual capacity. The smallest min cut (as a set of vertices) is the one consisting of s and all vertices reachable from s by arcs with nonzero residual capacity. The largest min cut is the one consisting of the complement of t and all vertices that can reach t by arcs with nonzero residual capacities. What can you say about a particular edge (x, y) with respect to these two cuts?

Comment: Aren't there still min cuts between the two which we are not accounting for?

Comment: That was a hint, not a complete solution.